# Интернет-магазин, как добавить товарам категории и сделать поиск по ним?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, интернет-магазин

Решил сделать небольшой интернет-магазин, чтобы разобраться в механизмах работы на практике. И встала задача добавить товарам категории и сделать поиск по ним. Как это лучше реализовать?

```
public class Product
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}

public class Category
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Или забыть как страшный сон и просто категории записывать в строку через запятую?

```
public class Product
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Categories { get; set; }

}
```

Какие плюсы и минусы у каждого способа? Как будет выгоднее с точки зрения производительности?

Comment: Судя по всему у вас будет связь многие-ко-многим. Для этого нужна вспомогательная таблица, которая хранит пары ключей категорий и магазинов. В EF Core последних версий можно обойтись и без неё, она генерируется автоматически. Вот, можете почитать https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php

Comment: @SmorcIRL Да,они генерируются,но вообще есть ли смысл,если задача состоит по сути в том ,чтобы научить работать с List<String>?

Comment: @SmorcIRL Просто хочется изначально делать по-человечески,чтобы потом в процессе не встал вопрос,а нафиг я все запихал в List , и не пришлось все по новой переделывать.Но перспектива общения с гигантскими Linq строками тоже не радует.Да и хотелось бы понять,насколько сильно "лишние" таблицы влияют на производительность

Comment: Из двух представленных вариантов, конечно, первый. Представьте, что понадобится добавить описание к категории. Во втором варианте это невозможно.

Comment: Вот, кстати, попробуйте ответить на этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66156561/5045688 - как раз ваш второй вариант.

Comment: Тут не будет никаких лишних таблиц, хотите работать с реляционной базой - работайте по правилам. Linq запросы на `IQueryable` преобразуются в SQL код, который уже за счёт индексов на стороне СУБД будет выполняться достаточно быстро.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы))

Comment: По поводу [производительности](https://youtu.be/t-Yf-c4FoXg?t=588)